# How can I extract skills from a resume using python?

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining

I am looking at how to extract a set of skills from an unstructured resume format using Python. Please note that, though I have a basic idea of NLP, I am completely new to Python.

Comment: Hello there, the question is way too broad according to the norms...

Comment: Let me give you a basic idea of what steps you can consider for your first iteration: (1) create a dictionary of skills; (2) parse the resume text, as a start consider python nltk library http://www.nltk.org, especially tokenize the resume by sentences and words. (3) find matches between your vocabulary of skills and words

Comment: Thanks Yauhen! This was helpful, trying in these lines. :)

Comment: @AnshulaAcharyya  any luck? I'm trying to do the same.